# Proving that a set is not consistent

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Ok so i was given the following problem:
**if** $\Sigma \vdash \psi $ **then** the set $\Sigma\cup${$\lnot\psi$} is **not consitent** .Prove it by using only the theorems of **completeness and correctness**

which basically say that: **$\Sigma \vdash \psi \Leftrightarrow \Sigma\vDash\psi$** or in other words: when a set of types $\Sigma$ **is consistent its also satisfiable and backwards**

Any ideas??? Remember we cannot use proof by contradiction, we want to prove by using only the above theorems.

Comment: What is $[\psi]$?

Comment: i added parentheses now, is it better? Makes sense to you?

Comment: $\{\psi\}$ would make it even clearer. However, don't you mean that this set _is_ consistent? The problem as written is incorrect.

Comment: no its not. I say if $\Sigma \vdash \psi$   is true , then the set created out of union of $\Sigma$ and $\psi$ is not consistent

Comment: This is wrong in that case. Provided $\Sigma$ is itself consistent, then adding any statement which it proves won't make it inconsistent.

Comment: oh crap. i am so sorry my friend. i fixed it now

Comment: Okay, now that we got it right - show that $\Sigma\cup\{\neg\psi\}$ can prove $\psi\land\neg\psi$.

Comment: can you give me a more clear answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to completness and correctness, your problem is equivalent to showing that if $\Sigma\models\psi$ then $\Sigma\cup\{\neg\psi\}$ is not satisfiable.  Both of the statements "$\Sigma\models\psi$" and "$\Sigma\cup\{\neg\psi\}$ is not satisfiable" assert, by definition, that certain sorts of models cannot exist. Write out and compare what those sorts of models are, and you'll have your proof.

Comment: what do you mean by models?? i am even more confused now... give me an example at least.... thanks

Comment: If you don't know what models are, then what do you mean by "$\Sigma\models\psi$ and what do you mean by "satisfiable"? The usual definitions of those concepts involve models.

Comment: by model you mean valuation $\upsilon$??

Comment: Aha! It seems you're asking only about propositional logic, not first-order logic. In that case, yes, substitute "valuation" for "model".  ("Model"
 would be the appropriate concept in first-order logic, where the same result holds.)